American Pillar Arborvitae Flowering or Diseased?
What is happening at the tips of this American Pillar arborvitae?
The plant is 3 years old and part of a row of about 15 similar plants.  It is shorter than the others and started developing brown growth at the tips at the start of summer.  The photo below shows this growth at the start of winter. I do not see this grown on any of the other American Pillar or Emerald Green arborvitae planted around the same time in the same area.
Does this growth indicate disease, pests or development of normal cones?


There are no obvious clues as to why but these details may assist:

arborvitae can get mites but you would have seen the webbing during the summer.  Still, the plant may have been weakened if it had been under attack during the hot summer
they naturally shed a portion of their growth every fall
the cones look fine but the dead tips indicate dryness or stress

I suggest watering the plant thoroughly to prepare for winter. Once a week for an hour or so should do.  A slow soaker hose or drip irrigation would be even better.
Next spring take some time to observe the plant for pests and any signs of disease.  I have seen spider mites and mealy bug on my own cedars and was surprised as I thought these were only indoor plant problems.
